# Exporting field data in many to many relationships using django-input-output only shows primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-import-export

I am trying to export the data from my database from the django admin page using the django-import-export package. When I export a model, I also want to show the data in a particular field for every object in a many to many relationship.

It looks something like this:

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.part_number

class Bin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
class ItemResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('part_number', 'description')

@admin.register(Item)
class ItemAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
    resource_class = ItemResource

class BinResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Bin
        fields = ('name', 'item__part_number')

@admin.register(Item)
class ItemAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
    resource_class = BinResource
```

The way I would expect this to work is that if I export Items, I will get a document that has all the part numbers in one column and the description in another. This works just fine. However, I would also expect that when I export Bins, one column would show all the names, and another column would display a list of all the part numbers of the items that are associated with the bin. What I actually get is a column called part_number, but there is nothing in any of the columns.

If I replace `fields = ('name', 'item__part_number')` with `fields = ('name', 'item')`, There will be a column titled item, but it will contain a list of primary keys, which is not helpful. How can I export this to show the information in the related fields I am looking for?

Note, I have done this before using foreign keys, I just can't get the many to many field to work. I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation showing how represent the various model relationships using the dunder notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the exported m2m column to contain a different field, you can simply pass the name of the field when declaring the `ManyToManyWidget` on the field.

For example:

```py
from import_export.widgets import ManyToManyWidget

class BinResource(ModelResource):
    
    item = Field(
        attribute='item',
        widget=ManyToManyWidget(Category, field='part_number',
                                        separator='|')
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Bin
        fields = ('name', 'item')
```

This would result in the `part_number` being displayed in the exported column, instead of `id`, for example:

```
name,item
name1,part1|part2
```

Comment: This worked! 
Note that the import for the ManyToManyWidget is 
`from import_export.widgets import ManyToManyWidget`